# Missing c# assemble for PerfSDK single user

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015, axapta, dynamics-365

I wend through documentation to create [performance test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/perf-test/perfsdk-tutorial) for AX 365. I  cannot build project because I am missing assemble in VS 2015 'MS.Dynamics.TestTools.DispatcherProxyLibrary.ApplicationForms'. Could anyone point me in a direction where I can download it or how to get this assemble?

Comment: At what point does it complain about a missing assembly, can you provide the code that needs it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are working with folder `C:\PerfSDK` as described in your [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/perf-test/perfsdk-tutorial). The folder contains a number of assemblies, such as

- MS.Dynamics.TestTools.ApplicationFoundationProxyLibrary.dll
- MS.Dynamics.TestTools.ApplicationFoundationUIHelpers.dll
- MS.Dynamics.TestTools.ApplicationPlatformProxyLibrary.dll
- MS.Dynamics.TestTools.ApplicationSuiteProxyLibrary.dll
- MS.Dynamics.TestTools.ApplicationSuiteUIHelpers.dll
- MS.Dynamics.TestTools.FoundationTestCommonProxyLibrary.dll
- MS.Dynamics.TestTools.SubledgerProxyLibrary.dll
- MS.Dynamics.TestTools.UIHelpers.Core.dll

Namespace `MS.Dynamics.TestTools.DispatcherProxyLibrary.ApplicationForms` is used in each of the listed assemblies. You need to make sure that required assemblies have been added as `References` to your project.

Please take a look at the sample project in `C:\PerfSDK\SampleProject`.